# How to use SonarSwift(Sonarqube) plugin in Jenkins in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have installed `lizard` but I'm getting this error when I build my job in Jenkins:

```
11:00:22.363 ERROR - Lizard Report not found /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxxxxxx/sonar-reports/lizard-report.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxxxxx/sonar-reports/lizard-report.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:623)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:806)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
    at com.backelite.sonarqube.swift.complexity.LizardReportParser.parseReport(LizardReportParser.java:61)
    at com.backelite.sonarqube.swift.complexity.LizardSensor.parseReportsIn(LizardSensor.java:51)
    at com.backelite.sonarqube.swift.complexity.LizardSensor.execute(LizardSensor.java:73)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:177)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:291)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:286)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
```

I have installed the Sonarswift plugin in Sonarqube manually. It seems that issue is with `Lizard`. Jenkins and Sonarqube server are on different machine. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: @RalfFriedl No, I think the sonar-runner will create the file/folder for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying to implement this use-case and reading many blogs and answers on the internet. I came to a conclusion that you cannot install on Xcode on ubuntu. It is specifically designed for MacOS. You can't even install the `xcodebuild` command line tools, as they are only available on MacOS.

I found this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404884/building-ios-project-with-jenkins-on-ubuntu-linux):

> The xcodebuild tool is part of the Xcode SDK from Apple — it's only
>   available for download on Mac OS X. You cannot simply use the official
>   iOS tools to build on a computer that isn't running OS X.
>
> This means that, if you have a Jenkins job which builds an iOS app, it
>   must be built on a Mac.